# Rdi not responding while new version upgrade is available . Error displayed Java was started but returned exit code 1

Tags: ibm-rational

Java was started but returned exit code = 1
Rdi is not starting after it shows the message new version is available. It reaches to the point of entering password and then hangs.

Please help. Only way I get to launch it successfully by deleting existing workspace and adding copy from archive.